# android error eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: android

When i am connecting mysql database with android   i am getting this error:

```
11-21 05:34:47.060: I/dalvikvm-heap(2288): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.961MB for 804304-byte allocation
11-21 05:34:47.170: D/dalvikvm(2288): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5017K/5148K, paused 105ms, total 105ms
11-21 05:34:47.640: D/(2288): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7033ad8, tid 2288
11-21 05:34:48.310: W/EGL_emulation(2288): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 05:34:48.740: D/OpenGLRenderer(2288): Enabling debug mode 0
11-21 05:34:48.860: I/Choreographer(2288): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Please Help

Comment: These messages look completely unrelated to sql. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.in/androidCall/check.php");

Comment: not able to establish connection to mysql database

Comment: The LogCat output you have provided, apart from being formatted poorly, is unrelated to the error you describe. Can you please provide LogCat output relating to the SQL database

Comment: 11-21 06:39:31.160: D/dalvikvm(1400): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 5016K/5172K, paused 114ms, total 114ms
11-21 06:39:31.680: D/(1400): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb78a9ad8, tid 1400
11-21 06:39:32.340: W/EGL_emulation(1400): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-21 06:39:32.900: D/OpenGLRenderer(1400): Enabling debug mode 0
11-21 06:39:33.090: I/Choreographer(1400): Skipped 102 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
try {
   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    httppost = new HttpPost("example.in/androidCall/check.php");
} catch(Exception x) {
   Log.e("HTTP", "Exception occured", x);
}
```

then see what `x` is

Comment: 11-21 06:23:37.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-21 06:23:37.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-21 06:23:37.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-21 06:23:37.110: E/AndroidRuntime(2839):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 06:23:53.890: I/Process(2839): Sending signal. PID: 2839 SIG: 9